# Executing method by yaml

Tags: java, scala, reflection, yaml, execute

My yaml file is

```
myYaml.yaml
myVal1:  "println(\"Hello Yaml\")"
myVal: "if (1 == 1) println(\"First statement!\") else println(\"Second statement\")"
```

both executing successfully by my code in scala

So far I have a executed condition in yaml that runs successfully
This variable 'myval' is in yaml file.

```
'''myVal: "if (1 == 1) println(\"First statement!\") else println(\"Second statement\")"'''
```

and
This variable 'myval1' is in yaml file too.

```
'''myVal1: "println(\"Hello Yaml\")"'''
using
'''

import scala.reflect.runtime.universe
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox
'''
```

and in class i have

```
'''val myStringExecTest: ToolBox[universe.type] = universe.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader).mkToolBox()
   myStringExecTest.eval(myStringExecTest.parse(confVar2.getString("myVal1")))
'''
```

Now, I want to execute my function from yaml as

```
if abc//some variable from my class where yaml will be called
= true
do this
else if
xyz //some variable from my class where yaml will be called
do that
else 
this
```

I am unable to get values based on some variables from the class. How can I achieve this?

Comment: do I get it straight, you are trying to put java code in your yaml file, and trying to execute that? Besides that: if ( 1 == 1 ) -> this is about the most redundant conditional statement I've ever seen.

Comment: Yes. I am doing in scala though. I am trying to put scala code in my yaml file and execute it. I have some conditions in my class based on certain variables, I want to bring that portion of the code to yaml so that i can easily modify any conditions later from the yaml instead of going into code each time.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have Scala code as a config file, with the code base ramp-up it would be a disaster to maintain them.